# How to update GUI timer before long-run code starts?

Tags: c#, winforms

Program is about counting words in txt files.
I have two forms. Form1 is about selecting files and words. Those data im passing to form2 where im starting GUI timer and algorithm for counting words. But algorithm is executed faster than GUI timer loaded.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CountWords();
}
```

[Form2 class](https://pastebin.com/p3hPgk2z)

Comment: Start [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). *"algorithm is executed faster than GUI timer loaded"* - is not true, timer is loaded and started in `InitializeComponents()` (in form constructor), but it can't run its events because `CountWords` blocks UI thread.

Comment: I Suggest to use another thread to call your CountWords() function. In this thread, call functions by Invoke to update your GUI if it have to.
If you don't need to have a responsive Form during the couting, call CountWords in a public function after its creation and not in the Load event.

Comment: Why are you opening a file on a timer? Does the file content change over time and you need to update the the UI with the new content? If that's the case, see also the [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) class. This class raises different events when a watched file is modified/deleted etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of blocking the UI Thread with CountWords, run this method on a background thread using the Threadpool

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            new WaitCallback(CountWords));
    }
```

Then, make sure to marshal ANY calls to UI controls back to the UI thread that you make from the background thread:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> word in words)
        {
            // Need to marshal this back onto the UI thread
            var itemToAdd = word.Key + " " + word.Value + "x";
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(AddItemToListView), itemToAdd);
        }
```

And then our AddItemToListView method will add the item on the UI thread:

```
    private void AddItemToListView(string item)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Comment: Whoops, yeah meant to write BeginInvoke. Thanks.

Comment: Error CS0123 No overload for 'CountWords' matches delegate

Comment: Sorry, you need to update your CountWords method to be private void CountWords(object param)

Comment: Thread-to-thread operation is not valid: Access to the listView1 control came from a thread other than the thread within which it was created. :(

Comment: On what line of code? Did you follow my code because the AddItemToListView() method is Invoked onto the UI thread. Please update your question and post all your source code.

Comment: Please note this line this.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(AddItemToListView), itemToAdd);

Comment: You can't access the ListViewItemCollection from the background thread. You need to first pull the list of files into a List<string> and instead access that from CountWords. So instead of ListView.ListViewItemCollection files;, you should have List<string> files;   then this.files = files.Select(f => f.Text);   Change your foreach loop to foreach(string file in files) { ..... } and using (var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))